# Objects bouncing off each other, javascript/classes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a canvas of many balls that bounce off each other and update velocity accordingly. I've been trying to do this within the object's class, but I am not sure if I'm going about it the right way.

Here's the main file, the part I'm having trouble with, or where I imagined the solution would be is the checkIntersections function of this file and the class file.

```
let molecules = [];
let numOfMolecules = 50;

let rad = 20;

let row = 5;
let col = 5;
let gridHeight;
let gridWidth;

let moleculeKey;
let tempArray;
let draw_grid = true;


function setup() {
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    background(150, 178, 164);
    createMolecules();
}

function createMolecules() {
    molecules = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numOfMolecules; i++) {
        molecules.push(new Molecule(i, rad));
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(150, 178, 164);

    gridWidth = window.innerWidth / col;
    gridHeight = window.innerHeight / row;

    splitIntoGrids();
    checkIntersections();
    drawGrid();
    renderGrid();
    resetBalls();
}

function splitIntoGrids() {
    moleculeKey = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        moleculeKey.push([]);
        for (let j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            moleculeKey[i].push([]);
            molecules.forEach(molecule => {
                if ((molecule.position.x + molecule.rad > j * gridWidth) &&
                    (molecule.position.x - molecule.rad < j * gridWidth + gridWidth) &&
                    (molecule.position.y + molecule.rad > i * gridHeight) &&
                    (molecule.position.y - molecule.rad < i * gridHeight + gridHeight)) {
                    moleculeKey[i][j].push(molecule.moleculeIndex);
                    //console.log(moleculeKey);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

function checkIntersections() {
    for (let i = 0; i < moleculeKey.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < moleculeKey[i].length; j++) {

            // if a cell contains more than one molecule, store the molecules into temporary array
            if (moleculeKey[i][j].length > 1) {
                tempArray = moleculeKey[i][j];

                // loops through each molecule in the temporary array
                for (let k = 0; k < tempArray.length; k++) {
                    for (let l = k + 1; l < tempArray.length; l++) {

                        // calculate distance of the molecules between each other
                        let distanceMolecules = p5.Vector.sub(molecules[tempArray[k]].position, molecules[tempArray[l]].position);

                        //get the length of vector
                        let vectorLength = distanceMolecules.mag();

                        //checks if molecules are intersecting
                        if (vectorLength < molecules[tempArray[k]].rad + molecules[tempArray[l]].rad) {
                            molecules[tempArray[k]].bounce = true;
                            molecules[tempArray[l]].bounce = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function resetBalls() {
    for (let i = 0; i < moleculeKey.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < moleculeKey[i].length; j++) {
            if (moleculeKey[i][j].length > 1) {
                tempArray = moleculeKey[i][j];
                for (let k = 0; k < tempArray.length; k++) {
                    for (let l = k + 1; l < tempArray.length; l++) {
                        let distanceMolecules = p5.Vector.sub(molecules[tempArray[k]].position, molecules[tempArray[l]].position);
                        let vectorLength = distanceMolecules.mag();

                        //checks if molecules are not intersecting
                        if (!vectorLength < molecules[tempArray[k]].rad + molecules[tempArray[l]].rad) {
                            molecules[tempArray[k]].bounce = false;
                            molecules[tempArray[l]].bounce = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For my object class, I don't know and can't figure out how to reference both the 'self/this' molecule and the molecule it bounced off from so that I can get its new velocity. I hope that makes any sense.

```
class Molecule {
    constructor(_i, _max_rad){
        this.moleculeIndex = _i;
        this.rad = rad;
        this.position = createVector(random(this.rad,width-this.rad),random(this.rad, height-this.rad));
        this.velocity = createVector(random(-2,5),random(-2,5));
        this.bounce = false;
    }

    render() {
      if (this.bounce) {
        let dx = this.position.x - molecules[???].position.x;
        let dy = this.position.y - molecules[???].position.y;
        let dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        console.log("dx = " + dx);
        console.log("dy = " + dy);
        console.log("dist = " + dist);
                
        let normalX = dx / dist;
        let normalY = dy / dist;
                
        let midpointX = (this.position.x.x + molecules[???].position.x) / 2;
        let midpointY = (this.position.x.y + molecules[???].position.y) / 2;
                
        let dVector = (this.velocity.x - molecules[???].velocity.x) * normalX;
        dVector += (this.velocity.y - molecules[???].velocity.y) * normalY;
                
        let dvx = dVector * normalX;
        let dvy = dVector * normalY;
                
        this.velocity.x -= dvx;
        this.velocity.y -= dvy;
                
        molecules[???].velocity.x += dvx;
        molecules[???].velocity.y += dvy;
      }

        push();
        translate(this.position.x,this.position.y)
        ellipse(0,0,this.rad*2,this.rad*2);
        pop();
    }

    step() {
        this.position.add(this.velocity);
    }
}
```

If there's any questions I can answer to try and make my problem clearer let me know, thank you.

Comment: Rather than set `bounce = true`, try setting `bounce` to be a reference to the other molecule it's colliding with. However, you will still encounter problems if a molecule collides with two other molecules at the same time. You'd probably be better off having collision be part of the molecule's movement logic.

Comment: Is having it be a part of the movement logic something completely different than what I have, or is it more a matter of moving the code, with maybe some changes?